# ArrayList Cast in java Combo box

Tags: java

Hi there i have this code

```
public void comboCountry(List<Countries> cs) {
    country = db.fillComboCountries();
    DefaultComboBoxModel dcbm = (DefaultComboBoxModel) CountryComboBox.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < country.size(); i++) {
        String row[] = new String[country.size()];

        //row[i] = String.valueOf(country.get(i).getCountryId());
        row[i] = country.get(i).getCountryName();
       // row[i] = country.get(i).getCountryCode();
        dcbm.addElement(row);
    }             
}
```

with `country = db.fillComboCountries();` i query the database  and load everything into an ArrayList.
The Arraylist is country.
When i load my data into combobox i get 
`[Ljava.lang.String;@fdfc58`

how can i avoid that and get the value that i want?
I have try with `Arrays.tostring()`, but i get also [ ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `dcbm.addElement(row);` use `dcbm.addElement(country.get(i).getCountryName());`

With this, you will add individual elements of an array rather than array itself. Also you would avoid creating arrays with every item in the country list.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new String array in each iteration, you should initialize the array before the for loop:

```
String row[] = new String[country.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < country.size(); i++) {
    ...
}
```

If you only want to add the countryName in each iteration, you don't need the array at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < country.size(); i++) {
    String countryName = country.get(i).getCountryName();
    dcbm.addElement(countryName);
}
```

Or:

```
for (Country c : country) {
    dcbm.addElement(c.getCountryName());
}
```